# Parse JSON dictionary within list Python 3.6

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, parsing, boto3

I am trying to parse a `JSON` response from a `boto3` `describe_isntances()` call. The response is a dictionary in a list. I am not getting the output I expect. What I need to do is parse the dictionary for the `Value` of `Key` when `Key` is equal to `email`. I also need to print a warning if that key/value pair does not exist in the response. At this point I am stuck. Below is my code, sample `JSON`, expected output, and the output:

`CODE:`

```
import boto3
import json

conn = boto3.resource('ec2')
client = boto3.client('ec2')

instances = conn.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])

for instances in instances:
    host_ids = instances.id
    email_tag = client.describe_tags(Filters=[{'Name': 'resource-id','Values': [host_ids,]}])
    for item in email_tag['Tags']:
        if item['Key'] == 'email':
            tag_value = item['Value']
        else:
            tag_value = print("Tag not found!")
    print(host_ids,tag_value)
```

`JSON:`

```
{'Tags': [{'Key': 'AZ', 'ResourceId': 'i-xxxxxxx', 
'ResourceType': 'instance', 'Value': '2'}, {'Key': 'KubeClusterId', 
'ResourceId': 'i-xxxxxxxx', 'ResourceType': 'instance', 
'Value': 'bug-fix'}, {'Key': 'NodeNum', 
'ResourceId': 'i-xxxxxxxxx', 'ResourceType': 'instance', 
'Value': '1'}, {'Key': 'KubeType', 'ResourceId': 'i-xxxxxx', 
'ResourceType': 'instance', 'Value': 'Node'}, {'Key': 'Name', 
'ResourceId': 'i-xxxxxxx', 'ResourceType': 'instance', 
'Value': 'bug-fix'}, {'Key': 'Tier', 'ResourceId': 
'i-xxxxxxx', 'ResourceType': 'instance', 'Value': 
'internal'}, {'Key': 'application_name', 'ResourceId': 'i-xxxxxx', 'ResourceType': 'instance', 'Value': 'bz'}, 
{'Key': 'cost_center', 'ResourceId': 'i-xxxxxxxx', 
'ResourceType': 'instance', 'Value': 'xxxx'}, {'Key': 'email', 
'ResourceId': 'i-xxxxxxxx', 'ResourceType': 'instance', 
'Value': 'foo@bar.com'}, {'Key': 'environment', 
'ResourceId': 'i-xxxxxx', 'ResourceType': 'instance', 
'Value': 'test'}, {'Key': 'initiative_number', 'ResourceId': 'i-xxxxxx', 'ResourceType': 'instance', 'Value': 'inxxxxx'}, 
{'Key': 'kube_env', 'ResourceId': 'i-xxxxxxxx', 
'ResourceType': 'instance', 'Value': 'bug-fix'}, {'Key': 
'portfolio', 'ResourceId': 'xxxxxx', 'ResourceType': 
'instance', 'Value': 'px'}, {'Key': 'utan', 'ResourceId': 'i-xxxxxx', 'ResourceType': 'instance', 'Value': 
'blazewater'}], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'dhdhdhdhdhdhd', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'content- 
type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'content-length': '3171', 'vary': 
'Accept-Encoding', 'date': 'Tue, 04 Dec', 'server': 
'AmazonEC2'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

`EXPECTED OUTPUT:`

```
i-xxxxxx foo@bar.com
```

or

```
i-xxxxxx Tag not found!
```

`OUTPUT:`

```
i-xxxxxx None
```

or

```
Tag not found!
```

Comment: `tag_value = print("Tag not found!")` should be `tag_value = "Tag not found!"`.

Comment: When I do that every single line of output is `i-xxxxx Tag not found!` when the tag is indeed in the `JSON`..

Comment: You have to add `break` after finding the key with value 'email'. `if item['Key'] == 'email':  tag_value = item['Value']; break`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep iterating the loop after finding the desired `dict` that overwrites the previous value.
You have to get out of the loop as soon as you find the desired `dict`.

```
for instances in instances:
    host_ids = instances.id
    email_tag = client.describe_tags(Filters=[{'Name': 'resource-id','Values': [host_ids,]}])
    for item in email_tag['Tags']:
        if item['Key'] == 'email':
            tag_value = item['Value']
            # get out of loop if found
            break
    else:
        # tag value if not found
        tag_value = "Tag not found!"

    print(host_ids,tag_value)
```